# Best way to change individual views styles in a multi Theme app

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a `ListView` with a `BaseAdapter` that can have many different `inflated` `views`. I'm implementing tree Themes that user can choose from within the app. Everything was great until I needed to change the appearance of a row `TextView` in the `ListView` depending on the Theme user has chosen.

I have a solution where I'm on the fly testing like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        switch (type) {
        case TYPE_ACTIVE: // inflate active accounts
            if (theme == SettingsManager.InterfaceTheme.light)
                convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.a_login_roaster_light, null);
            else if (theme == SettingsManager.InterfaceTheme.dark)
                convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.a_login_roaster_dark, null);
            else
                convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.a_login_roaster_def, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_row1);
            viewHolder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_row2);
```

As you see I change the appearance by inflate a ny row layout. This is working and everything but is there a better way to do this since the layout is same only color or font size must change? I'm using the android-support-v7-appcompat.jar and have the Theme.AppCompat.Light Theme in my Application Manifest as default Theme. I made some Themes with this wondeful tool, [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

Here is the Style created with [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/), I post one of tree styles since they are the same. This is the "light" version file located in res\values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- File created by the Android Action Bar Style Generator

     Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
     Copyright (C) 2012 readyState Software Ltd

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<resources>

    <style name="Theme.theapp_light" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_theapp_light</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.theapp_light</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.theapp_light</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.theapp_light</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.theapp_light</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.theapp_light</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_theapp_light</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_theapp_light</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.theapp_light</item>


    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.theapp_light" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_theapp_light</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_theapp_light</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_theapp_light</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.theapp_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.theapp_light" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_theapp_light</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.theapp_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.theapp_light" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">  
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_theapp_light</item>  
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.theapp_light" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_theapp_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.theapp_light" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_theapp_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.theapp_light" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_theapp_light</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_theapp_light</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_theapp_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.theapp_light" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_theapp_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.theapp_light" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_theapp_light</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.theapp_light.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.theapp_light</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.theapp_light</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And this is color resources style located in res\values

```
<resources>
    <color name="pressed_theapp_light">#CCFC4C5D</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: What are the differences between the 3 layouts? Only the styles or you also change the structure? Maybe you can post them to help understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: I updated all the content below to include the style `multiListItem` that I defined to setup an automated style on the list items.

Here is the way I use on my app to let the user switch between themes:

First I prepare the different themes in the file `styles.xml`, here is an easy example where I modify the default basic colors on the system:

```
<!-- *** DEFAULT THEME *** -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">?mainColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">?darkColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorTertiary">?lightColor</item>
    </style>

    <!-- *** ORANGE THEME *** -->
    <style name="AppThemeOrange" parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="mainColor">@color/orange_main</item>
        <item name="lightColor">@color/orange_light</item>
        <item name="darkColor">@color/orange_dark</item>

        <item name="multiListItem">@style/OrangeListViewItemStyle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- *** PURPLE THEME *** -->
    <style name="AppThemePurple" parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="mainColor">@color/purple_main</item>
        <item name="lightColor">@color/purple_light</item>
        <item name="darkColor">@color/purple_dark</item>

        <item name="multiListItem">@style/PurpleListViewItemStyle</item>
    </style>
```

I also add the 2 styles needed for the 2 themes:

```
<style name="OrangeListViewItemStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/OrangeMain</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

<style name="PurpleListViewItemStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/PurpleMain</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>
```

The style `multiListItem` is then called on the list row items, for this case I used it in this layout (the layout inflated for each row in my list):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/filter_list_child_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/filter_list_child_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:longClickable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filter_list_child_textview"
        style="?multiListItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So I have a default theme that is actually loading references from the specific Orange and Purple themes.
In order to do this I added the references in the file `values\attrs.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
       <attr name="mainColor" format="reference"/>
       <attr name="lightColor" format="reference"/>
       <attr name="darkColor" format="reference"/>

       <attr name="multiListItem" format="reference" />
  </resources>
```

I also created all the `selectors` I call in the styles in the folder `color`, here is `orange_dark.xml` for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/TextGray"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/OrangeLightBackground"/>
    <item android:color="@color/OrangeDark"/>
</selector>
```

Once all this is prepared, I load the right theme using the shared preferences. The theme is just available as a normal setting through a list preference populated with this:

```
<string-array name="themes_strings">
        <item>Purple</item>
        <item>Orange</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="themes_values">
        <item>purple</item>
        <item>orange</item>
    </string-array>
```

Then to retrieve the theme selected in the settings, I just use this simple function:

```
public int getThemeID() {

        String themeSelected = _sharedPrefs.getString(PREF_KEY_THEME, DEFAULT_THEME);
        if(themeSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("orange")){
            return THEME_ORANGE_ID;
        }
        else if(themeSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("purple")){
            return THEME_PURPLE_ID;
        }
        else{
            return THEME_PURPLE_ID;
        }
    }
```

The constants are defined using the themes references directly:

```
public static final int THEME_ORANGE_ID = R.style.AppThemeOrange;
public static final int THEME_PURPLE_ID = R.style.AppThemePurple;
```

Then the theme selected is applied on the activities using this line:

```
setTheme(mPrefs.getThemeID());
```

`mPrefs` is just a helper class gathering all my shared preferences getters and setters.

Hope it will give you some ideas!

Comment: This is what I also do, exactly the same. The question is if user click a `ListView` item and the item color or font must change depending on what Theme currently being used. My Question code sample show just this. Maybe what I'm doing is not questionable and a reasonable good way to do it but if there is a better way I like to learn.

Comment: In your case you are not only changing the styles, you are also changing the layouts, the differences between the layouts cannot be set with styles? It would avoid all these conditions.

Comment: Yea your right i´m inflating the row layout depending on light,dark,def Theme. This was the first idea that came to me, but I have many XML files now representing the "row" in it's different states. I dont have to inflate new layouts I could instead just do the same test, light,dark,def Theme and change the row TextView font or color in the `viewHolder`. The rows have the same layouts only appearance change. So like I do it in my question code sample is overkill, inflating, right, any better idea?

Comment: Can you post the differences between 2 of your styles? AnywayI will update my answer with what I do on my lists, I don't have access to my code right now but I will be able to give you an update next Monday

Comment: Updated my question with the styles. The difference is only the color in my tree themes. I post the xml "styles_theapp_light.xml". Thanks love to see what your code does

Comment: I updated my answer with what I use on my row items, hope it helps!

Comment: I see, when you click a row, Orange or Purple `multiListItem` is loaded. Maybe I could make a `selector` inside the `multiListItem` for `state_pressed` to get my desired pressed `listview` row effect, Problem solved cool :). This was what i wanted