# Changing style programmatically ANDROID

Tags: android, styles

I am building an app that uses simple text and I would like to add an option to change the text color.

My question is would the most efficient way to do this be to assign all text views to a single STYLE resource and change the values of the STYLE resource ( if this is even possible)

or

would it be better to make multiple style resources and some how programmatically change every single View's style?

Is there anyway to inherit style from a parent or put all of the Views into a single object so its easier to just change the style of that one object?

Comment: Do you need to change the color of all the text views or only some of them?

Comment: All of them. All of the text.

Comment: I may have a solution for you but it requires to define a list of colors, if it is ok for you I will post it.

Comment: If it helps me get to my end goal any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have a look to this answer I gave on another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19107734/2206688 (you maybe won't need the part about the lists)